# What functional of DJI MSDK is affected by module 'library-anti-distortion'?

Tags: android, dji-sdk

I want to reduce size of my apk that use DJI SDK. I fount [here](https://github.com/DJI-Mobile-SDK-Tutorials/Android-VideoStreamDecodingSample/blob/master/android-videostreamdecodingsample/app/build.gradle) that I can exclude some parts of DJI SDK. I use DJI SDK 4.10 so i cant exclude 'fly-safe-database' because it is supported only for 4.11+. So I want to exclude 'library-anti-distortion'. But I don't sure my app will work correctly.

What is this module used for? What functional of DJI SDK can work incorrect after removing this module?

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation it is only needed for the Mavic 2 Pro and Mavic 2 Zoom.

The methods `getTranscodingDataRate` and `isLensDistortionCalibrationNeeded` in the class `VideoFeeder` are the only places in the documentation where the anti-distortion feature is mentioned.

From the information provided it is most likely that the raw video stream from Mavic 2 Pro and Mavic 2 Zoom requires an anti-distortion-computation step as the lens/CCD-chip of the camera differs from the other DJI drones.

Therefore excluding the library will only affect the video stream if using the two drone models mentioned above.